# How to deploy Play Framework API App in Azure Web App

Tags: scala, api, azure-web-app-service, playframework-2.3

I'm new in putting answers, so I hope I'm not being naïve in the question. Please do consider that while you read the question. I want to deploy a Scala Play App in an Azure Web App. I checked all the documentation about deploying Play app as .zip with the dist command. In the Azure Web App documentation, I found the option '/ZipDeployUI' to send my .zip file. I tried to launch the app with the command in [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying). But it simply is not working.

Command I used:

```
apitry101 - Dplay.http.secret.key='ObZAt^1e2535_<ahje96aQuHbfFfBaigF=Yg62B0zbEBhxp;]MF/7QiodZY=9nzL'
```

Does any one knows that is it posible or I am simply losing my time here? Should I go just with heroku?

Comment: kindly provide more detail when you say 'its not working'